# DNN ModuleID not being passed from the code behind to the ascx

Tags: angularjs, vb.net, dotnetnuke

Backstory: I use a DNN (DotNetNuke) content management system to host VB.NET/Angular1 modules.

I'm currently having an issue where a value in the code-behind is not accessible in the View.ascx of my module. This is causing a fatal runtime error.

[The code behind where the value is being passed to a publicly defined variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URYA1.png)

[The View.ascx where the variable is being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xysiq.png)

```
Erreur: icod est présentement indisponible. 
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FRANCO-NORD-www1\DesktopModules\icod\View.ascx(2): error BC30451: 'modID' n'est pas déclaré. Il peut être inaccessible en raison de son niveau de protection. ---> System.Web.HttpCompileException: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FRANCO-NORD-www1\DesktopModules\icod\View.ascx(2): error BC30451: 'modID' n'est pas déclaré. Il peut être inaccessible en raison de son niveau de protection.
à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
à System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
à System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath)
à DotNetNuke.UI.ControlUtilities.LoadControl[T](TemplateControl containerControl, String ControlSrc)
à DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.WebFormsModuleControlFactory.CreateModuleControl(TemplateControl containerControl, ModuleInfo moduleConfiguration)
à DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleControlFactory.LoadModuleControl(TemplateControl containerControl, ModuleInfo moduleConfiguration)
à DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost.LoadModuleControl() --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne --
```

I noticed that they reference View.ascx(2) as if there are two physical versions of the file in the project or on the server, but this is not the case.

Any ideas on what may be going on here? Please let me know should the post require additional information.

Comment: Is your namespace different?  I see from your screenshot that it is expecting the codebehind in class: Christoc.Modules.icod.View.  I don't see the namespace in the code-behind screenshot, but if that is different, you need to fix it.

Comment: I've updated the code-behind screenshot to display the Namespaces it's inheriting. As you can see there's a few redundant includes there that I have to clean up - trying to get a functional module before I do so.

Comment: @Scottbee, the `(2)` in the message refers to line 2 in `View.ascx`

Comment: If it's not a mismatch in the namespace, like @DotNetNuclear suggests, it may be that you need to compile before the view will see that property in the codebehind

Comment: @bdukes I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project a few times as well as restarting IIS. The issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved the issue by rebuilding my local development instance of DNN to a version higher than that of the production instance and rebuilt the module. I believe one of the DLLs we use in our environment, PetaPoco was causing an issue when the module was installed on a lower version of DNN. Previously my local copy of DNN was 9.1.0.367, it is now 9.1.1.129 whereas the production instance is at 9.1.1.113 .

It's not ideal that fixing it required a total reinstantiation of my development environment, but I believe a simple upgrade to an equal or greater version of the destination site would have fixed the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess, based on the updated screenshot, is that your full class name is incorrect in your View.ascx.  It is expecting a codebehind class "Christoc.Modules.icod.View", but no namespace is defined in your partial class which means it will default to your default project namespace (which I am assuming is different).

I would try two things.

1) Ensure the namespace is defined in your View.ascx.cs

```
Namespace Christoc.Modules.icod
    Partial Class View
        ...
    End Class
End Namespace
```

2) Make sure you are building your module's assembly into the correct /bin folder of your DNN installation.

Comment: Wrapping my View class in the Namespace causes a different error. See the below pastebin. The error mentions that I need to include "Implements System.Web.UI.UserControl" but I'm not sure why I should have to do that.

https://pastebin.com/BgrJwBcW

Comment: @Scottbee does your class still have the `Inherits icodModuleBase` statement?  Does that `icodModuleBase` class inherit from `UserControl` (or a class that inherits from `UserControl`, like `PortalModuleBase`)?

Comment: Your View class inherits icodModuleBase.  Does your icodModuleBase class inherit from PortalModuleBase?

Comment: @DotNetNuclear The inheritance goes as follows: icodModuleBase > PortalModuleBase > UserControlBase > UserControl .

Comment: @Scottbee - everything seems correct. Did you verify that the dll is built in the /bin folder?  Also, check in IIS to make sure Visual Studio did not create a virtual directory on the DesktopModules folder or any folder under DesktopModules.  If you see any virtual directories on your DNN application, just remove them.